# Pass sql column values to an array usnig Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays

I am working with an ASP.net webform and have a SQL select statement that generates a table with a single column. All values of that column would need to be added to an array using javascript, to replace manual entry. Here is a working array example:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var addressPoints = [

        [35.393617, -119.038301],
        [33.485073, -86.785173],
        [35.218721, -80.849652],
        [38.678598, -90.373175],
        [37.786996, -90.414874],
        [44.946816, -124.016506]

     </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 12

        }),
            latlng = L.latLng(35.824322, -98.763128);

        var map = L.map('map', { center: latlng, zoom: 3.8, layers: [tiles] });

        var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

        for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
            var a = addressPoints[i];
            var title = a[2];
            var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
            marker.bindPopup(title);
            markers.addLayer(marker);
        }

        map.addLayer(markers);

    </script>
```

The Coordinates column has been formatted exactly as the Manual entry data you saw in the example above. The below example does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var addressPoints = [
//    Values from a column  "Coordinates" go here//
//    [35.393617, -119.038301],
//    [33.485073, -86.785173],
//    [35.218721, -80.849652],
//    [38.678598, -90.373175],
//    [37.786996, -90.414874],
//    [44.946816, -124.016506]
        ];

</script>
```

If you have any idea how to plug in the Coordinates column into an array using Javascript,  I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: so you want the array to look like: ["35.393617, -119.038301",
    "33.485073, -86.785173",
    "35.218721, -80.849652",
    "38.678598, -90.373175",
    "37.786996, -90.414874",
    "44.946816, -124.016506"] ?

Comment: My sql table has a column that already looks just like the manual data I've provided above. All I want to accomplish is to replace those coordinates with a Sql Column values.

Comment: The data in my column looks like this: [35.393617, -119.038301],
    [33.485073, -86.785173],
    [35.218721, -80.849652],
    [38.678598, -90.373175],
    [37.786996, -90.414874],
    [44.946816, -124.016506]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have already displayed the Coordinates value in the DOM element "Coordinates" - so try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var addressPoints = [
        document.getElementById("Coordinates").value;
    ];

</script>
```

Comment: still doesn't populate

Comment: Perhaps i'm misunderstanding your requirement. You already have code that produces the coordinates as a single element shown above FROM the database, correct?

Comment: Please show the code that generates the coordinate element in the DOM. Also show as much of the markup as possible.

Comment: I guess my main concern is how to build an array using a column data generated from SQL.

Comment: As soon as I replace document.getElementById("Coordinates").value; with [35.393617, -119.038301]  I see the result

Comment: Let me rephrase. How are you retrieving the coordinates data from the database and presenting it to the page for use in the javascript array? Personally I would be sure i'm populating the data as I expect it to a DOM element (div, hidden textbox, label, etc), then grab the value of this element and alert it to see what is present in the element. Modify accordingly to get the desired result.